# Azure Search Custom Analyzer

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We are trying to use a custom analyzer (KeywordAnalyzer) using Azure Search Rest api-version: 2015-02-28-preview.

The Index definition code you see below is copied exactly from Microsoft docs.
This works if we put the Analyzer Type to CustomAnalyzer. However, if we make a single change by changing the analyzer type from CustomAnalyzer to any other analyzer such as KeywordAnalyzer, you get a Bad Request error when creating the Index and the Index is not created.

Would appreciate if anyone coud tell us how we can specify an Analyzer.

Many thanks

```
 {
           "name":"homes",
           "fields":[
              {
                 "name":"Id",
                 "type":"Edm.String",
                 "key":true,
                 "searchable":false},
              {
                 "name":"IdStd",
                 "type":"Edm.String",
                 "searchable":true,
                 "analyzer":"my_analyzer"}
           ],
           "analyzers":[
              {
                 "name":"my_analyzer",
                 "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
                 "tokenizer":"my_standard_tokenizer",
                 "tokenFilters":[
                    "my_asciifolding",
                    "lowercase"
                 ]
              }
           ],
           "tokenizers":[
              {
                 "name":"my_standard_tokenizer",
                 "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.StandardTokenizer",
                 "maxTokenLength":20}
           ],
           "tokenFilters":[
              {
                 "name":"my_asciifolding",
                 "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.AsciiFoldingTokenFilter",
                 "preserveOriginal":true}
           ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm from Azure Search. What's the error message you're seeing together with the BadRequest response code?

Edit:
I reread you question. Potentially you are specifying the tokenizer and tokenFilter properties for the KeywordAnalyzer. These properties only apply to the CustomAnalyzer. Please let me know if you find the documentation insufficient or confusing. We'll make sure to make it more clear and easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The docs do not reflect this. For example if we want a keyword analyzer and want to apply the lowercase tokenFilter to it, is this not possible? Also, we did take everything outand left just the analyzer (Keyword). This time we get no errors but searches are not successful. Is there anyway to look at the indexed terms? Do you have any examples showing the usage of custom analyzers. Many thanks

Comment: We'll be publishing more content in January. The Keyword analyzer is a predefined analyzer that can't be customized. However, you can create a custom analyzer with the Keyword tokenizer and Lowercase token filter. Here is an example:
{
    "name": "my_analyzer",
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
    "tokenizer": "keyword",
    "tokenFilters": [
        "lowercase"
    ]
}
Can you describe what queries you're issuing and what are the results you'd expect?

Comment: Many thanks. Great Job! This works for us now. I originally had the code { "name":"my_analyzer","@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.KeywordAnalyzer" } without any other attributes - which created the index but produced no search results. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: I'll need you to provide more details: what were the queries that didn't return any results, what were the documents you expected to be returned, how did you define the field against which you were searching?

Comment: @Yahnoosh , hey I'm trying to use the same structure but it says im missing odataType. used the same one that you wrote here. I'm not able to set it up on the field also because I get the following error:
"The name of the language analyzer to use for the field. This option can be used only with searchable fields and it can't be set together with either searchAnalyzer or indexAnalyzer. Once the analyzer is chosen, it cannot be changed for the field. Must be null for complex field"